# AngularJS: Local JSON file works in factory but live API doesn't

Tags: angularjs

I found this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Eoq0zmv5NnOpHvyccaS?p=preview) in this OLD [article](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angularjs-creating-service-with-http.html) in my research to access API via a factory rather than in my controller. The plunker works fine but it is accessing a local JSON file whereas I will be accessing a live API feed.

I forked and modified the code to point to a live API feed which I tested in the browser and the feed at the URL is working but everything in the plunker went blank. Here are the steps I took to fail.

I modified the HTML to match the API field names like so:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>$scope.foo</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in foo">{{item.Zipcode}} - {{item.City}}</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>$scope.foo2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in foo2">{{item.Zipcode}} - {{item.City}}</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>$scope.bar</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in bar">{{item.Zipcode}} - {{item.City}}</li>
    </ul>

    <br/>

    <h3>And here is what you get if you just return the promise returned by $http.get():</h3>
    <pre>{{test | json}}</pre>
  </body>
```

and then substituted the URL in place of the local JSON file in the service:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

   //The clean way
   $scope.foo = myService.getFoo();

   //The "but I really like callbacks" way.
   myService.getFoo().then(function(data) {
      $scope.foo2 = data;
   });

   //The "common callback" pattern
   myService.getBar(function(data) {
      $scope.bar = data;
   });

   //So what happens if I just return 
   // whatever $http.get() returns?
   $scope.test = myService.testHttpGetResult();
});

app.factory('myService', function($http, $q) {
   return {
     getFoo: function() {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.get('http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/LA&jsoncallback=?').success(function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(){
          deferred.reject();
       });
       return deferred.promise;
     },
     getBar: function(callback) {
       $http.get('http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/LA&jsoncallback=?').success(callback);
     },
     testHttpGetResult: function (){
       return $http.get('http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/LA&jsoncallback=?');
     }
   }
});
```

Now there is no data.

Here is my forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0eoEE6cA5GK1BRkvab6w?p=preview).

Is something else required to access a live API rather than a local JSON file?

Comment: I know it's probably obvious but have u checked with fiddler does the app work and return the structure you require?

Comment: Fiddler allows you check what is actually going between client nd server. Check it out at it is one of the best tools you can have when working with the web. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Thanks. I am downloading it now. Based on reading the description, will this replace the Postman extension I use in Chrome? AND is the mono package safe to install on my Mac?

Comment: It's a separate application so it won't replace it just lets you see the traffic. Also if you are testing multiple browsers it will mean you don't have to install multiple add-ons. The mono part should not interfere with anything on your mac but Im not a person who has a mac so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your plunker and this is a working version:

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/bngUpRlV7OQjLzR4OKM1?p=preview

You are encounter a cross domain restriction of the browser, normally it isn't allow to make an ajax request to a site with a different domain.

There are two common technique to bypass the restriction, [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Luckily, the external API, that you are using, have a JSONP support already, so you can use it like this:

```
getFoo: function() {
  return $http.jsonp('http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/LA&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
              .then(function (resp) {
                return resp.data && resp.data.result;
              });
}
```

There are three things to consider:

1. to use JSONP in angular, the url must be in this format:

   http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/LA&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
2. the result array actually in the `resp.data.result` or if you use `success()` it is in `data.result`.
3. The `$http` service already return a promise, there is no need to create an another promise using `$q.defer()`, you can return it right away.

Comment: Thanks. So that I can learn this -- Do you always use jsonp for a URL feed or just ones outside of your own domain? I am creating a laravel 4 app using Angular so the API feed will be the same domain as the Angular app.

Comment: Yeah, use JSONP only for ones that outside your own domain. I've included the explanation in the answer.